# Modify meta data before saving to database

Tags: php, filters

Is there a way in wordpress to modify meta values before they are stored to the database? At first I thought I could do it with the "[update_post_metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_meta_type_metadata/)" filter but unfortunately this filter does not work like other filters.

A workaround would be to store the values to a different meta data field in the update_post_metadata filter but it would be better if there would be another way.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing this? What problem does it solve? Do you have an example of what you tried already with `update_post_metadata`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to store a value from a datepicker timezone-neutral. Either as an ISO 8601 string or an unix timestamp. So I have to transform and reformat the value before I store it to the database.

Comment: couldn't that be done just before the `update_post_meta()` call, or in javascript?